# svn export changes and save locally

Tags: linux, svn, command-line

What's the best way to export changes between 2 SVN revisions and save the changes (files/folders) locally?

Possibly through the command-line?

Thanks

Comment: You mean save them as patch files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
svn checkout -r {2006-02-17}
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html

esssentially you would "checkout" two folders based on dates.

EDIT: A simple folder compare at that point would give you what files changed, and what changed in the files.

EDIT2: Perhaps something along the lines of :

```
svn diff -r BASE:HEAD foo.c
```

or

```
svn diff -r HEAD
```

Not sure if you can do something like

```
svn diff -r BASE:HEAD
```

where you can update base to a number and head to a number.
My suspicion is that since this works:

```
svn diff -r BASE:14 foo.c
```

you should be able to replace base and head with numbers and just compare all the files.

I'm really not sure though.

Comment: Is there no other way of doing it? I've seen what I'm after in tortoiseSVN, but I'm using Linux and I don't seem to be able to do this using RabbitVCS

Comment: To be honest I'm not heavily fluent in SVN, but that's my first thought of what you're trying to accomplish, if you're simply wanting to diff one version of your repo with a later version,I'll update my response, so it's easier to see.